# count rows with duplicate values and group by multiple columns using PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Dose anyone know how to count rows with duplicate values and group by multiple columns using PowerBI DAX? Below is the example, how to generate the row count by name and group? Thank you in advanced.

Data source table1:

[image]

Expected table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a new table, not just a measure then try this:

```
NewTable = summarizecolumns(
table1[name]
,table1[group]
,"row count", calculate( COUNTROWS (table1))
)
```